# List Dropbox Files using REST API

Tags: c#, api, rest, oauth, dropbox

I want to list all the files of a folder from my own Dropbox account on my website. I was going to use C# and the Dropbox Rest API but from reading the documentation it appears that I can't do that without first getting the user to go to dropbox to receive an authorisation token.

Is this correct? Is there anyway I can return the data in code without asking the user to log in?

Comment: Why would you want to publicly expose the contents of your Dropbox on your website?  What exactly is the purpose of what you are trying to do?  If you have files you want to distribute why not just serve them directly from your website?

Comment: If you are trying to host a website via Dropbox take a look at http://pancake.io or http://droppages.com

Comment: I wanted to allow the members of my site to upload files for others to see but want to avoid storing them on my server to minimise the risk of viruses being uploaded.

Comment: Then using Dropbox still sounds like a bad idea because then they may upload viruses to your dropbox which syncs to your personal computers instead which seems like a worse idea to me.

Answer (score 8):

Actually no.

You need to authenticate first using OAuth and than get list of files. Documentation is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api)

Also as tutorial here:

https://github.com/geersch/DropboxRESTApi